# how to calculate percentage in sql without using traditonal methods

Tags: sql

```
         A        B       A/B   
       461264   307638  66.7178 
       334673   217099  64.869  
       372045   220354  59.2278 
       427186   181755  42.547  
       435871   214099  49.1198

Total 2031039   1140945 56.1754
```

-> this average is calculated by using `(214099/435871) * 100`.

I want a solution in which I have to take only one column i.e a/b and by using this only I want to calculate the average percentage.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: How is this `(214099/435871) * 100` related to your expected result which seems to be `(1140945/2031039) * 100`
?

Comment: no difference sir, let discuss in another way , in column A/B we have fraction of column A and column B , is it possible to find average percentage  of column A/B without involving column A and B ?

Answer (score 1):

For the average percentage (not overall percentage), perform the calc, then select the average:

```
select avg(x.pc)
from
(
select a/b as pc
from MyTable
) x
```

For the overall percentage, you need:

```
select x.a/x.b
from
(
select sum(a) a, sum(b) b
from MyTable
) x
```

Comment: firstly thank to u for replying . In first method i won't get exact avg percentage. and in second query i have to query on both the column a and b which i don't want , i tried this method earlier also , but i want something other that this.Thanks in adv

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
select avg(a / b)
from t;
```

Or this:

```
select avg(a) / avg(b)
from t;
```

The two answers are different.  I can't easily tell from your question which version you want.